# Hodge decomposition on non-compact manifolds

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, hodge-theory

Let $(\mathcal{M},g)$ be a compact Riemannian manifold without boundary. Then we have the well-known Hodge decomposition

$$\Omega^{k}(\mathcal{M})\cong\mathcal{H}^{k}(\mathcal{M})\oplus\mathrm{ran}(\mathrm{d})\oplus\mathrm{ran}(\delta)$$

where $\mathcal{H}^{k}(\mathcal{M})$ denotes the space of harmonic $k$-forms.

> Are there any known results for *compactly-supported* forms in the non-compact case?

For the non-compact case, the only relevant theorem I could find is due to Kodaira in the case $(\mathcal{M},g)$ is complete and reads

$$\Omega^{k}_{L^{2}}(\mathcal{M})\cong\mathcal{H}^{k}_{L^{2}}(\mathcal{M})\oplus\overline{\mathrm{ran}(\mathrm{d}\vert_{\Omega^{k-1}_{c}})}^{\Vert\cdot\Vert_{L^{2}}}\oplus\overline{\mathrm{ran}(\delta_{\Omega^{k+1}_{c}})}^{\Vert\cdot\Vert_{L^{2}}}$$

where $\Omega^{k}_{L^{2}}(\mathcal{M})$ is the space of smooth $k$-forms, which are also in $L^{2}$. See also reference (2) below. However, in my case, I am only interested in the case of $\Omega^{k}_{c}(\mathcal{M})$, which is a subspace of $\Omega^{k}_{L^{2}}(\mathcal{M})$. Furthermore, can one relax the completeness assumption in this case?

---

**References:**

1. K. Kodaira:  *Harmonic fields in riemannian manifolds (generalized potential theory)*. Annals of Mathematics 50, pages 587–665, 1949.
2. E. Amar: *On the $L^{r}$ Hodge theory in complete non compact Riemannian manifolds*, Mathematische Zeitschrift (287), pages 751–795, 2017.

Comment: How would this work for $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard metric? Presumably, $\mathcal{H}^1$ should be translation invariant, but there is no translation invariant compactly supported $1$-form. (Recall that $H^1_c$ of the line is $1$-dimensional.)

Comment: @DavidESpeyer: Harmonic contribution would be zero, just like in the $L^2$ case.

Comment: Okay, so the goal is not to give representatives for $H^k_c$ ?

Comment: Exactly. The goal is to see whether it is possible to decompose a compactly supported k-form in a similar way as on compact manifolds.

Comment: The issue is that for $\mathbb R$ with the standard metric the image of $d$ is a cxdimension $1$ subspace, so the only way to get a decomposition of this form is to sum it with a $1$-dimensional subspace, but there is no canonical (i.e. translation-invariant) $1$-dimensional subspace, so no decomposition of this form can exist without replacing $d$ by something very different.

Comment: @WillSawin If I understand Moishe's response to me, that it not correct. Let $f_n$ be the step function which is $1$ on $[0,1]$ and $-1/n$ on $[-n,0]$. Then $f_n$ (or, a smoothed version of it) is in $d \Omega_c^0$ for all $n$, but, in $L^2$, the $f_n$ approach the characteristic function of $[0,1]$. So the $L^2$ closure of $d \Omega_c^0$ is actually all of $\Omega^1$, not something codimension $1$. To me, this demonstrates that $L^2$ on spaces of infinite volume is just a bad idea, but I think that is what Moishe is saying.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Please feel free to correct!